# iPhone Map Application

Tags: iphone

How to Open iPhone Map Application from our application and passing the parameter to that?

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=yourLattitude, yourLongitude"]];
```

must open the map application on your location. You can also use Google Maps inside your application with MapKit framework.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in iOS4. It opens the google maps web app, which is pretty non-performant on old hardware.